# Лишние стили CSS на проекте

Tags: vue.js, scss

День добрый! Прошу помощи, при запуске проекта на Vue в инспекторе отображаются лишние стили не подходящие к данному блоку. Подскажите в чем проблема может быть? Проект на VUE из препроцессоров юзаю SCSS
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эти стили может быть swiper добавляет ?

Comment: @MonkeyMutant нет, на всех элементах такая штука

Comment: отключите стили от swiper и проверьте - будут ли эти постронние стили